# How to create a Keras layer from tf.math.segment_sum

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I would like to use the `tf.math.segment_sum` function in a Keras layer but I don't get the dimensions right.

As an example, I would like to sum the values of `x_1` grouped by `id` in the dataframe `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':     [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4],
                   'x_1':    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                   'target': [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]})
```

The 'model' I created looks as follows:

```
input_ = tf.keras.Input((1,), name='X')

cid = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int64', name='id')

summed = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.segment_sum(x[0], x[1]), name='segment_sum')([input_, cid])

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_, cid], outputs=[summed])
```

I get an error about the rank:
`ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'segment_sum/SegmentSum' (op: 'SegmentSum') with input shapes: [?,1], [?,1].`

What do I do wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried flattening the arguments, `x[0]` and `x[1]`? I think removing a dimension (i.e. `tf.reshape(len(x[i]))`) might fix the issue.

Comment: I changed the following line: `summed = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.segment_sum(x[0], tf.reshape(x[1], (1,))), name='segment_sum')([input_, cid])`. This removes the error. When I do a 'prediction' like `model.predict([np.asarray([[6]]), np.asarray([0])])`, I get the expected output `array([[6.]], dtype=float32)`. However, when I enter `model.predict([np.asarray([[6]]), np.asarray([5])])`, I expect the same output but i get an error: `ValueError: Mismatch between expected batch size and model output batch size. Output shape = (6, 1), expected output shape = shape (1, 1)`. Any idea?

Comment: Why are you reshaping to (1,)? I think you want to reshape to (len(x[1]),), as I stated above.

Comment: `len()` does not work on a tensorflow tensor... Would you know a different way how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using `tf.gather`. The working code is as follows:

```
input_ = tf.keras.Input((1,), name='X')

cid = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int64', name='id')

summed = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.gather(tf.math.segment_sum(x[0], tf.reshape(x[1], (-1,))), x[1]), output_shape=(None,1), name='segment_sum')([input_, cid])

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_, cid], outputs=[summed])
```